# HTML/CSS/ColdFusion same code produces different

Tags: css, firefox, coldfusion

The same html/css code is producing different colors from the href in two different modules.  I'm in Firefox for both programs, on the same machine. Both modules are the result of a form submit.
Module 1:

```
<body class = 'bodybak'>
<cfinclude template = 'memb-init.cfm'>
   ...stuff that has no formatting
<cfset personid = form.persid>
 <cfif personid EQ 'none'>
 <div class = 'col bodybak' style = 'width:50%; margin:auto; padding:2%' >
 <p class = 'fixes'>EZNP cannot find you in our system.  If you are sure you have set up a username and password, please contact your administrator for assistance.  Otherwise, sign in as a new person. </p>
 <p class = 'repcap' style = 'text-align:center'> 
    <a href = "#tostart#" style = 'color: ##679c9c !important'>Return to First Screen</a>
 </p>
</div>

<cfelse>...
```

Result of first module:
[image: Result of first module:]

Module 2:

```
<body class = 'bodybak'>
<cfinclude template = 'memb-init.cfm'>
      ...stuff that has no formatting
<cfif numboth + numeml + numcity Eq 0> <!---all the nums set up earlier--->
    <div class = 'col bodybak' style = 'width:50%; margin:auto; padding:2%' >
      <p class = 'fixes'>EZNP cannot find you in our system.  If you are sure you have set up a username and password, please contact your administrator for assistance.  Otherwise, sign in as a new person. </p>
      <p class = 'repcap' style = 'text-align:center'> 
         <a href = "#tostart#" style = 'color: ##679c9c !important'>Return to First Screen</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </cfif>
```

Result of second module:
[image: result of module 2]

I'm trying to get the second result in both cases.  I can't find anything that differs between the two.  Nor can I find any workaround that gets the first one working properly.

Can someone spot what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you used Inspect Element to see what's going on? Maybe depending on the page it's loaded on, some other CSS is overriding the link style?

Comment: You do realize that `<a>` tags have a `:visited` pseudoclass which if the page was both visited and a different style from the unvisited page, it will be colored differently.

Comment: TRose -- yes I used the inspector and it showed the correct css.

Comment: @user12031119  I didn't know that, and it could well be the problem.  Is there a way to override that?

Comment: @BettyMock Just make the `:visited` link the same color as the unvisited link. 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: @user12031119,.  I put a:visited in my css with the color I want, but it did not help.

Comment: The css  @user12031119 suggested definitely works. If it's not behaving correctly for you it has to be either a) incorrect code/css b) color is being overridden by another class or c) possibly caching.  Post your new code and a screen shot of the inspector

Comment: @SOS I'll get to it shortly.  I have done this in many places and not had this problem so  I have never set up visited and unvisited links It could nonetheless be some subtlety in the code.  Thanks for taking an interest.